# $[L:K]$ is a Galois extention with Galois group G. Describe a map G to $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-groups, galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Suppose K is a field containing p th roots of unity. Suppose $[L:K]$ is a Galois extention with Galois group $G$. Let $ a \in L$ not in $K$ s.t $a^p \in K$. Describe a nontrivial map $G \to \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$.

I am thinking about $f(a)=a^2$ such that $f|_K=id$. Does this define $f$ completely? And after that does $G \to \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ map would be $f \to 2$. I think my answer is meaningless.

- The first step should be proving $L=K(a)$ or something and the considering
- a map from $G \to \Bbb Z/\Bbb Z_p$.

Please help me with a full answer. I think I have solved this before but now I can't out of panic. I have an exam on Monday so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming the map needs to be a group homomorphism (otherwise, literally any peicewise-defined map would work)? Are ther any other conditions on anything, like $K$ having characteristic $0$, or $p$ being prime?

Comment: $p$ needs to be prime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some hints to get you started.

Let $b = a^p$, so that $a$ is some choice of $\sqrt[p]b$. In particular, the field $K(\sqrt[p]b)$ is a subfield of $L$.

**Question 1**: What is the Galois group of $K(\sqrt[p]b)/K$? Here, you will need to use the fact that $\zeta_p\in K$ - otherwise this extension may not be Galois. You will also need to use the fact that $p$ is prime and that $a\notin K$ - otherwise this extension might not have the right degree.

**Question 2**: Can you describe a map $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)\to\mathrm{Gal}(K(\sqrt[p]b)/K)$? Why is this map a surjective group homomorphism?

Comment: To answer your first question it should be $\Bbb Z_p$. As $\sqrt[p]b \mapsto \zeta_p^k \sqrt[p]b$ will give an isomorphism. I am confused about whether $\sqrt[p]b \mapsto \sqrt[p]{b^2}$ is legit or not otherwise it won't be $\Bbb Z_p$. Please help here.

Comment: For Qn 2 the map would be $f \mapsto f|_{K(\sqrt[p]b)}$ it is group homomorphism because it is just a restriction map. Am I correct? If so what is the conclusion from here?

Comment: $\sqrt[p]b\mapsto \sqrt[p]{b^2}$ is not legit. In general, $\sqrt[p]b$ and  $\sqrt[p]{b^2}$ do not have the same minimal polynomial.

Comment: And yes, the second map is just restriction. The Galois correspondence tells you that it's a surjective group hom. So you have an isomorphism $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\sqrt[p]n/K)\xrightarrow{\sim}\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and a surjective homomorphism $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)\to \mathrm{Gal}(K/\sqrt[p]n/K)$

Comment: The other way to think about this is that $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ acts transitively on $a$ and all its Galois conjugates, of which there are $p$.